# Writing ECMAScript Javascript Regex to Perl flavour (PCRE) / (PCRE2)

Tags: regex, pcre, ecmascript-2018

I'm having the below Regex which is written to support the ECMAScript Javascript flavour. However, this has to be re-written in the Perl flavour (PCRE) / (PCRE2)

```
(?<!x)(?<!\border\D*\W*)(?<!\border\D*number\W*)(?=(?:[._ –-]*\d){9})(?!9|66\D*6|00\D*0|(?:\d\D*){3}0\D*0|(?:\d\D*){5}0(?:\D*0){3})\d(?:[._ –-]*\d){4}
```

**The above regex has Set of rules in it, [Regex Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/oF8x6C/6)**

I don't have an idea in Perl on how to implement it, however if i could get a help on this, it would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this PCRE compliant regex equivalent of your Javascript regex:

```sh
\border(?:\s*number)?\W*\d+(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<!x)(?=(?:[._ –-]*\d){9})(?!9|66\D*6|00\D*0|(?:\d\D*){3}0\D*0|(?:\d\D*){5}0(?:\D*0){3})\d(?:[._ –-]*\d){4}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bXyrnO/2)

- The idea of the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` trick is to consume characters that you want to avoid, and that must not be a part of the match result.
- `(*F)` shorthand for `(*FAIL)`

Comment: Good old SKIP FAIL :-)

Comment: Thanks, that's the only work around for dynamic length lookbehind of JS

Comment: Not sure. Lets try it against ``order number+2222222222``

Comment: @Michail: `order number+2222222222` should not match as per original requirement

Comment: @anubhava, Hey anubhava, thanks for the solution. However, the regex pattern is missing the "order" test case.. In the solution, you have written it for "order number" how do i add for "order" like given in this demo? `https://regex101.com/r/bXyrnO/1`

Comment: @anubhava, I worked on it, and got this to work. 

`(\border\D*\W*)\d+(*SKIP)(*F)|(\border\D*number\W*)\d+(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<!x)(?=(?:[._ –-]*\d){9})(?!9|66\D*6|00\D*0|(?:\d\D*){3}0\D*0|(?:\d\D*){5}0(?:\D*0){3})\d(?:[._ –-]*\d){4}` 

hope i didn't do anything wrong and make it more complex. Thoughts?

Comment: @anubhava, When attempting to save the regex in the Genesys designer, it throws the following error. 

“Evaluation takes too long. Please check your regular expression.” Is there any way we can simplify the regex??

Comment: @anubhava ``order number+2222222222 should not match as per original requirement``. Isn't a regex at author's showed with regex demo in title post must be converted? If so then it match ``order number+2222222222``

Comment: @Michail: I trust original requirement should come from OP and here requirements are not specified just a complex regex was posted.

Comment: @anubhava, thank you very mutch for your explanation

Comment: @anubhava, i have posted the new question.. You can find it here 

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71787206/improving-the-performance-of-an-prce-regex-pattern)