# Improving the performance of an PCRE Regex Pattern

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, pcre, regex-group

I have the below regex here which is written to support the PRCE/PRCE2 format. However, this throws the following error **“Evaluation takes too long. Please check your regular expression.”** Is there any way we can improve the performance of this regex by simplifying it?

Also, the regex throws **"catastrophic backtracking"** error as well.

`(\border\D*\W*)\d+(*SKIP)(*F)|(\border\D*number\W*)\d+(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<!x)(?=(?:[._ –-]*\d){9})(?!9|66\D*6|00\D*0|(?:\d\D*){3}0\D*0|(?:\d\D*){5}0(?:\D*0){3})\d(?:[._ –-]*\d){4}`

**[Regex Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/WHbzLv/1)**

The above regex has set of rules in it. Please find the requirements of the regex.

1. First 5 numbers should only be masked in a 9 digit number.
2. Should not mask any numbers if the 'x' or 'X' precedes the 9 digit number.
3. If the "order" or "order number" string precedes the 9 digit numbers, then it should not be matched.
4. You can find the list of use cases for the same along with the rules in this link. [Usecases with requirements](https://regex101.com/r/WHbzLv/1)

Regex101 is giving me the exact output as expected but it has a performance issue. Need to simplify it.

Comment: @AmigoJack, regex pattern is only needed. :-)

Comment: Does it need to find the numbers within a full text? Or is it fine to match a complete string?

Comment: Please provide a string that cause catastrophic backtracking with this pattern.

Comment: @Kamesh: Does this work more efficiently for you? https://regex101.com/r/WHbzLv/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this refactored regex:

```sh
\b(?>x|order(?>[\W_]*number)?[\W_]*)\d+(*SKIP)(*F)|(?=(?>[._ –-]*\d){9})(?>(?>9|6{3}|0{3}|(?>\d\D*){3}00|(?>\d\D*){5}0{4})(*SKIP)(*F)|\d(?>\D*\d){4})
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WHbzLv/4)

Compared to your existing demo link it is taking almost half number of steps in the demo link.

Answer (score 1):

Other approach: expand the pattern!

```
~(*UTF)
    x (?<! \w x ) [\d._ –-]* (*SKIP) (*F)
  |
    order (?<! \w order ) [\W_]* (?:number)? [\W_]* [\d._ –-]* (*SKIP) (*F)
  |
    (?<res>
      [1-578]  (?: [._ –-]{0,3}+ \d ){2}  (?: 0{2}  [\d._ –-]* (*SKIP) (*F) )?
      (?: [._ –-]{0,3}+ \d ){2}
    )
    (?: 0{4} [\d._ –-]* (*SKIP) (*F) )?  (?: [._ –-]{0,3}+ \d ){4}
  |
    (?<res>
      0  (?: 0{2} [\d._ –-]* (*SKIP) (*F) )?  (?: [._ –-]{0,3}+ \d ){2}
      (?: 0{2} [\d._ –-]* (*SKIP) (*F) )?  (?: [._ –-]{0,3}+ \d ){2}
    )
    (?: 0{4} [\d._ –-]* (*SKIP) (*F) )?  (?: [._ –-]{0,3}+ \d ){4}
  |
    (?<res>
      6  (?: 6{2} [\d._ –-]* (*SKIP) (*F) )?  (?: [._ –-]{0,3}+ \d ){2}
      (?: 0{2} [\d._ –-]* (*SKIP) (*F) )?  (?: [._ –-]{0,3}+ \d ){2}
    )
    (?: 0{4} [\d._ –-]* (*SKIP) (*F) )?  (?: [._ –-]{0,3}+ \d ){4}
  |
    9 [\d._ –-]* (*SKIP) (*F)
~iJx
```

The pattern is indeed more long, but [2 times faster](https://3v4l.org/EDVGc#v8.1.5) and with [8 times fewer steps](https://regex101.com/r/WC7ovA/1).

Note that I uses a capture group to extract the first 5 digits and the 4 remaining digits are also consumed, but if you prefer, you can also remove this capture group and put the 4 remaining digits in a lookahead ([more steps](https://regex101.com/r/ZVQbez/1) but [more efficient](https://3v4l.org/1iUpZ#v8.1.5)).

I started the pattern with `(*UTF)` since it contains a dash out of the ascii range.

Comment: @ Casimir et Hippolyte,  does it work with PCRE Supported environments?

Comment: I would like to know if you can re-write the regex without starting with (*UTF), i tried removing but it is not working. can you modify without UTF and with capturing groups?

Comment: @Kamesh: Yes this pattern uses specifically the PCRE features. Could you give the language or the tool inside which PCRE is used.

Comment: @Kamesh: Removing the `(*UTF)` (or `(*UTF8)` or `(*UTF16)`) at the beginning may be problematic because a multibyte character is inside a character class. Without, bytes that compose this character may be used separately and not only inside the byte sequence of this character. As a workaround, you can eventually use the `u` modifier, but this one also expand the character classes `\d` and `\w` (and there negated version) to UTF8 characters.

Comment: What to do if the J and X flags are not supported by the regex engine? Is there any way we can re-write to support in such a way we can avoid the X and J flags? :)